# Rspec FactoryGirl :: Failure/Error expected: 1 time received: 0 times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, rspec, record

Hi i'm new on ruby on rails.

Currently i'm having a problem testing controller on rails using rspec and FactoryGirl. I'm trying to test activerecord for corresponding with my action 'show' but it didn't get through or received any. Is there anything that i can do to fix this? thank you

the error i got is :

```
 *Failure/Error: Employment::LevelAccess.should_receive(:find).with(@level_access.id.to_s).and_return(@level_access)
   (<Employment::LevelAccess(id: integer, employment_id: integer, accessiblity_id: integer, actions: string, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) (class)>).find("1")
       expected: 1 time
       received: 0 times*
```

Here are my codes

**level_access_controller.erb** :

context 'require instance' do

```
  before do
    @level_access = FactoryGirl.create(:level_access_2, employment_id: @employment.id)
  end

  describe 'Get id to Show' do

    it "should find the correct value to show" do
      Employment::LevelAccess.should_receive(:find).with(@level_access.id.to_s).and_return(@level_access)
      get :show, :employment_id => @employment.id, :id => @level_access.id        
    end

  end

  describe 'Get show' do

    before do
      get :show , :employment_id => @employment.id, :id => @level_access.id 
    end

    it "should render a show page" do
      expect(response).to render_template("show")
    end

    it "should not redirect to any page" do
      response.should_not redirect_to("hahahha")
    end

  end        

end
```

**FYI:** i also already make an instance for the employment as well.

**Factories/level_access.erb** :

FactoryGirl.define do

```
factory :level_access, class: Employment::LevelAccess do
    employment_id   {FactoryGirl.create(:employment).id}
    actions             'create,update,new,destroy,show'
end

factory :level_access_2, class: Employment::LevelAccess do
    actions             'show'
end
```

end

Comment: FYI : i'm using gem inherited resource which automatically add restful methods (such as new,destroy,show,index,etc) to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally figure it out by asking help from my project manager**

he quoted

**LevelAccessController** :

class Manage::Employments::LevelAccessesController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  defaults :resource_class => Employment::LevelAccess, :collection_name => 'level_accesses', :instance_name => 'level_access'

protected

```
  def begin_of_association_chain
        employment
  end

  def employment
    @employment ||= Employment.find(params[:employment_id])
  end
```

end

---

so i change the rspec which
 describe 'Get id to Show' do

```
it "should find the correct value to show" do
  Employment::LevelAccess.should_receive(:find).with(@level_access.id.to_s).and_return(@level_access)
  get :show, :employment_id => @employment.id, :id => @level_access.id        
end
```

end

**into**

```
        it "should find the correct value to update" do
          @employment.level_accesses.should_receive(:find).with(@level_access.id.to_s).and_return(@level_access)
          put :update, :employment_id => @employment.id, :id => @level_access.id
        end
```

since the begin_of association_chain relation in controller should have make the instance available for relation chaining in the rspec.

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
def show
  @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
end
```

in controller rspec

```
before do
  @emp = FactoryGirl.create(:employee)
  get :show , id => @emp.id
end

it "find the employee with provided id" do
  assigns[:employee].should == @emp
end

it "should render a show page" do
  response.should render_template('show')
end

it "should not redirect to any page" do
  response.should_not redirect_to("hahahha")
end
```

'assigns' allows u to access the instance variable from the controller in the spec. for more info on correct way of writing rspec, pls have a look at http://betterspecs.org/

Comment: Hi thanks for the link you've provided ( http://betterspecs.org/ ) .. i actually did what you've suggested but on other controllers..let see if i can make it work on this controller since it needed another id(nested model). thank you for your answer.